# how to require file from plugin directory of wordpress in theme page

Tags: wordpress

I want to require_once an html file from plugin directory of wordpress in the custom page of wordpress

i have tried

```
require_once(WP_PLUGIN_URL."/sinetiks-schools/images/t1.php");
```

but getting an error

```
require_once(): http:// wrapper is disabled in the server configuration by allow_url_include=0 i
```

Comment: you should change the server config `allow_url_include=0` - it can cause a lot of problems with 3rd party plugins and themes

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<?php
 echo '<img src="' . plugins_url( 'images/wordpress.png', dirname(__FILE__) ) . '" > ';
        $dir = plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ );
        var_dump($dir);
 ?>
```

Comment: The above  code is giving the path up to the theme which will not work . i want to include file from plugin folder not theme

Comment: when i var_dump(path) it is giving /home/traveldealsguru/inventive-data.com/memberwp/wp-content/themes/velocity/

Comment: Please recheck my answer.

Comment: the path i have used is correct WP_PLUGIN_URL."/sinetiks-schools/images/t1.php"  but it  is not including html file

Comment: it is giving an error "  wrapper is disabled in the server configuration by allow_url_include=0 "

Comment: use this :- require_once('../sinetiks-schools/images/t1.php'); Or require_once('/sinetiks-schools/images/t1.php');

Comment: have you try this or not?

Comment: I have moved the required  file from plugin to theme folder , now it is working